# Memory Management in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, maui

**Background:**
As previously as I know, .NET MAUI defines the service lifecycle throughout the app running. For example, the `MainPageViewModel` should be a static class and define the service as
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPageViewModel>()`, so we always get the same instance.

On the other hand, some service is created when we require such as `DetailPageViewModel` and define the service as `builder.Services.AddTransient<DetailPageViewModel>()`, so we get different instance every time we need and the GC should automatically release the instance when we don't need.

**Problem:**
I run the [.NET MAUI demo](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/dotnet-maui-workshop) (made by James Montemagno, Gerald Versluis, et al.) with [Rider IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) and then use [Rider Memory Debug Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Exploring_Memory.html) to check the memory usage for transient services. Every time I navigate to DetailPage and return back, the DetailPage and DetailPageViewModel will allocate the memory and keep alive in the memory (its occupied size increases).

[image]

So how exactly does the `builder.Services.AddTransient<>` work? What about its automatic GC mechanism? (From the results it looks like it's not working)

Comment: Garbage collection is not predictable. Unless app is running low on memory, there is no guarantee it will run. Advice: don’t worry about it.

Comment: The code that determines when GC should run, is developed with significant engineering effort. For 10 years, I had one case that required manual collection, because of library written by 3rd party (badly). And I have seen many failed attempts to manually handle the memory usage.

Comment: Raymond Chen's [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203): "Garbage collection is simulating a computer with an infinite amount of memory... If the amount of RAM available to the runtime is greater than the amount of memory required by a program, then a memory manager which employs the null garbage collector (which never collects anything) is a valid memory manager."

Comment: Garbage collection is used to keep the system have enough storage to at runtime. So you don't have to worry if there is any unuseful object not be recycled when the system run well.

Comment: @Shing Ming - did you ever determine how to free the memory for transient pages that are no longer used? I'm having a similar issue with my app. When ContentPages are popped from the navigation stack, they are occupying memory indefinitely for me even though these ContentPages, the associated ViewModels and children have no event handlers subscribed to long-living objects.

Comment: @cfischy 
I no longer researched it deeply after that because my main problem is I registered some subscriptions on the transient page, and it will continue the subscription even if I leave. So, my countermeasure to work around this odd situation is that

1. Use the ‘using’ statement to ensure the correct use of disposable objects if an object has an IDisposable instance.
2. Unregister all subscriptions before I leave the page.

I don’t know if this odd situation only appears in MAUI or is standard behavior in dotnet because this concern the GC Collection, which is a complex topic.